How to turn a just watch electrum wallet to HD
Hello everyone I have an electrum wallet and it's in just watch mode and I'd like to change it to an HD wallet in electrum. How to go about it if it's possible?

non-HD WO to HD WO
It seems Electrum supports both deterministic (HD) and non-deterministic watch-only wallets but you can't simply convert from one type of watch-only wallet to the other type of watch-only wallet.
You can create a new HD wallet and manually import into it the addresses from the old non-HD watch-only wallet. I'm not sure there is any reason to do this.

WO to spendable
If you want to convert a watch-only wallet to one that can spend the money watched by the watch-only wallet, you can't do that without additional data that isn't in the watch-only wallet (private keys).
It may help to read the description of Electrum Watch-only wallets at https://bitcoinelectrum.com/creating-a-watch-only-wallet/

A watch-only wallet is a wallet without any secrets in it that could be used to spend bitcoin.

If you have the private keys that are omitted from a watch-only wallet, you can import them into a new wallet following the guide at https://bitcoinelectrum.com/importing-your-private-keys-into-electrum/
